# What's the nicest proof of the formula for the sum of the $k$-th powers of the first natural numbers?

Tags: reference-request, induction, generating-functions, bernoulli-numbers, bernoulli-polynomials

Do you know of a text where I can find a nicely motivated proof of the formula for $1^{k}+2^{k}+\cdots+n^{k}$?

At the very beginning of page 68 of Professor H. S. Wilf's [generatingfunctionology](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf), one can find a pretty straightforward way to obtain it but, unfortunately, there aren't any comments there regarding the "sources" of the proof.

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that there is a discrete analogue of calculus called the "difference calculus" or the "calculus of finite differences" which allows you to evaluate sums the same way calculus allows you to evaluate integrals. If $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb R$ then $Df(k) = f(k+1) - f(k)$. Notice that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} Df(k) = f(n) - f(0)$ (because the sum telescopes). To evaluate $\sum_{k=0}^n k^3$ for example we need to find $f$ such that $df(k) = k^3$. So construct a table of anti-differences, like the tables of antiderivatives you find in calculus books.

Comment: Is it by induction?  I only know it for $k=1,2,3$.

Comment: It looks like that is problem 23 on that page. It would be convenient for those looking at your question if you would excerpt that question and any relevant parts of the text on which it depends.

Comment: @ChrisCuster: Sort of... By induction on $k$ one can prove at the very least that $1^{k}+\cdots+n^{k} = \frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}+p_{k}(n)$ where $p_{k}(n)$ is  a polynomial in $n$ whose degree is less than or equal to $k$.

Comment: In calculus, the derivative of $x^m$ is $m x^{m-1}$. The analogous result in the difference calculus says that the difference of $f(k) = k^{(m)}$ is nice, where $k^{(m)}$ denotes the "falling factorial" $k^{(m)} = k(k-1)\cdots (k-m+1)$.

Comment: @Jamai-Con See wikipedia's [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) page and references.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways to derive this formula. Perhaps the fastest is to prove that this is a polynomial of degree $k+1$ in $n,$ and use Lagrange interpolation.

Another way is to use the finite calculus. In calculus, we have $\int x^k \, dk = \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} + C.$

There is a formula in the finite calculus analogous to this. The finite calculus is based on the same idea as Stoke's theorem in the normal calculus: Things cancel. Particularly, if you have a complicated sum $\sum_{i=1}^n f(i)$ then maybe you can write $f(i) = F(i+1) -  F(i)$ for some different function $F.$ Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n f(i) = \sum_{i=1}^n F(i+1) - F(i) = F(n+1) - F(1)$$
via the telescoping identity.

So, can we write $i^k = F(i+1) - F(i)$ for some function $F$, to sum our series easily?

Well, not quite. But a closely related function can be written in that form! Namely, let's try looking at what happens when we take the `finite derivative' of a polynomial. The usual integral formula says to that $x^{k+1}$ is (almost) the integral of $x^k.$ So why not guess $F(i) = i^{k+1}$ and go from there? Expanding, we get

$$F(i+1) - F(i) = (i+1)^{k+1} - i^k = \sum_{n=0}^k \binom{k+1}{n}i^n.$$

So this isn't quite $i^{k}.$ But it's *close.* Namely, it's some constant times $i^k,$ plus some terms involving only lower powers of $k.$ So you use intuition from usual calculus: Subtract away the antiderivatives of the lower powers, divide, and then you've found your antiderivative of $i^k$ in the finite calculus! This can be turned into a recursive algorithm to find these antiderivatives. Try finding it!